# How to send vars to a function from module.exports and get some back?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm quite new to javascript and i'm trying to send one variable to a function, call an api from there and get the stats back into module.exports but I cant seem to figure it out....

Here's basically how my code is built:

```
function stuff(userArg) {

   (calling api magic here)

   var index = -1;
   for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(res['data']['playerstats']['stats']).length; i++) {
     if(res['data']['playerstats']['stats'][i]['name'] === 'deaths') {
        index = i;
        var userDeaths = res['data']['playerstats']['stats'][index]['value'];
        break;
      }
   }
   return userDeaths;
}

module.exports = {
   name: 'table',
   description: '.....'

   async run(messages, args) {
       const userArg = args.join(" ");
       stuff(userArg);

       console.log(userDeaths);
   }
}
```

It seems like it should work but I cant get it to work and its driving me mad... If anyone knows the reason i'd greatly apppreciate it!

Comment: What do you mean by "get the stats back into module.exports"? I'm curious whether you actually meant to use `args.joing` or whether it should be `args.join`, and there's nothing in your `run` function or `stuff` that is asynchronous, so I don't see a reason to mark the function as `async`.

Comment: Where's the API call? Why does `run` not do anything with the return value of `stuff()`? Why is `run` an `async` function?

Comment: haha no args.joing was a misspelling and this is how my code is structured but not how it looks atm... And yes I need to use async run for that as well (:

Comment: This is most likely XY problem. You can assign a property to module.exports object but then you'll have race conditions because they aren't  assigned at the time when they are accessed. 'await' for 'run' call and return the result from it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with module exports. You just forgot to assign the return value of the `stuff()` call to a local variable. Notice that `userDeaths` is not a global variable, you declared it in `stuff`, which means you cannot use it in `run`.

```
function run(messages, args) {
    const userArg = args.join(" ");
    const userDeaths = stuff(userArg);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    console.log(userDeaths);
}
```